# Hibernate doesn't generate SET fields

Tags: hibernate, class, netbeans, generator, pojo

I made a new project trying to use Hibernate on netbeans IDE.
I'm following the official guide  at this link:

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html

in order to configure the project.

So, this is my hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hdemic?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is my Hibernate.reveng.xml file:

```
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
    <schema-selection match-catalog="hdemic"/>
    <table-filter match-name="Users"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

When I go for generate class from POJO, all of my "entity class db" are created with all fields except "Set fields", I mean collection that are generated through relationships that are specified in hbm.xml file(RELATIONSHIPS MISSING!!!).

I have to add some property to my config or revenge xml file?
I try to do the same things with another computer(linux) and all is fine. I also think is problem of my installation or my computer (mac os).
Both has the same installation.

Please help me, thanks all.